# Sign up with Facebook - confirmation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Are there any safety concerns when implementing Signing up with Facebook feature? Facebook doesn't ask for credentials each time, so if somebody was logged in to Facebook previously, our button will allow to connect instantly and will just ask for permissions.

In my app, is it a good practice to confirm by send confirmation to e-mail address registered on Facebook? I thought of doing the following thing:

> When somebody signs up with Facebook, he's then redirected to sign up
>   page, where he can type the e-mail and password. E-mail is filled with
>   Facebook's one by default. Then, he gets emails to confirm account
>   registration - separate for typed e-mail and separate for Facebook's
>   e-mail, unless they are the same.

Does this approach make sense or is it an overhead?

Comment: The FB login dialog has an option of forcing the user to re-enter the FB password before proceeding (see docs), so that might be a suitable option for new sign-ups to your service. Demanding that for every single login afterwards might be over the top though, and will annoy users. Basically, keeping their account “safe” by logging out when they are done, is a user’s own responsibility IMHO.

Comment: Do you know if Google and Twitter have the same feature?